# String by string replacement

Tags: php

i got an array

```
$array = [
    "a" => "c",
    "b" => "d",
     "c" => "a",
     "d" => "b",
 ];
```

and a string `$text = "dcab";`

How can i replace with my array elements each letter on my string, im try to figure out by steps but not luck,

1.- `explode` my string

2.- for each letter `str_replace`, 
output will be: `bacd`

thank for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can't use [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) because of the big warning that it shows in the documentation:

> Replacement order gotcha
>
> Because str_replace() replaces left to right, it might replace a previously inserted value when doing multiple replacements. See also the examples in this document.

Then take a look at the [strtr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) function

```
echo strtr($text, $array);
```

Comment: I waste time thiking and testing with loops, never tought that easy. Thanks a Lot.